# Data Binding User Input C#

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

I am attempting to create data binding using a list of 3 roles (coach, referee, player). Depending on the role will display the data binding information. In my code I created 2 classes one for Member to get name and address, and a class for Roles to get the member role (coach, referee, player). When attempting to insert code to add the member to the list in the main class I get an error there is no argument to my member class; however shows the 2 strings for name and address I set up. How are there no arguments when I get; set name and address? Also DataMember and DataSource are not recognized when setting the data binding.

Member Class:

```
namespace WpfApp1
{
    class Member
    {
        string MemberName { get; set; }
        string MemberAddress { get; set; }

        public Member(string memberName, string memberAddress)
        {
            MemberName = memberName;
            MemberAddress = memberAddress;
        }
    }
}
```

Role Class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace WpfApp1
{
    class Role : List<Member>
    {
        public string MemberRole { get; set; }

        public Role(string memberRole)
        {
            MemberRole = memberRole;
        }

        public List<Member> Members { get { return this; } }
    }
}
```

Main Class:

```
namespace WpfApp1
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            List<Role> roles = new List<Role>();
            Role role1 = new Role("Member Role");
            role1.Add(new Member("Jay, Jones"));
            role1.Add(new Member("chris, cross"));
            role1.Add(new Member("John, jones"));
            Binding cboBindingSource = new Binding();
            Binding lboBindingSource = new Binding();
            cboBindingSource.Source = roles;
            lboBindingSource.Source = cboBindingSource;
            lboBindingSource.DataMember = "Roles";
            ComboBox.DataSource = cboBindingSource;
            ComboBox.DisplayMemberPathProperty("Role Name");
            ListBox.DataContextProperty
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Only one string argument is provided for the `Member` constructor in the `MainWindow()`, and this constructor only takes two, hence the no argument error.

Comment: Also setting a binding object as a source for another binding object (`lboBindingSource.Source = cboBindingSource;`) makes no sense.

Comment: Use either `role1.Members.Add(new Member(...))` or `roles.Add(new Member(...))`. If the former, don't forget to set `role1.Members = roles` first.

Answer (score 0):

There is no constructor in member class accepts one argument and defined one accepts two. Hence no argument error.Either pass role1.Add(new Member("Jay, Jones","India")); or  role1.Members.Add(new Member("aas","assa"));